# Query to search in all columns in table with joining

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am searching in all column data in the selected SQL table, and I have a join with another table, but my issue that the 2nd table has the same column name with tableA, how can I specify each column with its table.
So I declare the string to find and the table, if I remove the join it will work, but my issue only with joining

```
DECLARE @stringToFind varchar(max) ='%TELECOM%'
DECLARE @table varchar(max) ='tableA'
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @table + '] 
Left join    Table2 on
               Table2.Id= tableA.IdCategory  
WHERE ' 
SELECT @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''' + @stringToFind + ''' OR '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 

WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table 
AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar')

SET @sqlCommand = left(@sqlCommand,len(@sqlCommand)-3)
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
PRINT @sqlCommand
```

> `Ambiguous column name 'Type'.`

Answer (score 0):

"Select *" will return all columns from both joined tables. If both tables have a column with the same name it will be ambiguous.

Table qualifiers may help. Explicitly select the columns you want.

```
select T1.type atype,T2.type another_type, T1.*,T2.* from Table1 as T1 left join Table2 as T2 on T1.columnName= T2.columnName
```

Comment: I know how to do it, but the issue with this query  : + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']

Comment: see the 2nd Select

Answer (score 0):

If performance does not matter, there is a fully generic approach implying XML XQuery.

The following will search through all attributes in the generated XML using `contains()`, which is quite the same as `LIKE` as you are using it in your sample.

```
DECLARE @stringToFind varchar(max)='owner';

SELECT
(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.objects o
    inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id=o.object_id
    for xml auto,type
).query('//*[@*[contains(.,sql:variable("@stringToFind"))]]');
```

In my case the string "owner" is found in one table's attribute as well as in several column's attributes.

The result in my case looks like this (shortend):

```
<c object_id="5" name="ownertype" column_id="2" system_type_id="48"
<c object_id="7" name="ownerid" column_id="3" system_type_id="127" 
<o name="sysowners" object_id="27" schema_id="4" parent_object_id="
  <c object_id="27" name="id" column_id="1" system_type_id="56" use
  <c object_id="27" name="name" column_id="2" system_type_id="231" 
  <c object_id="27" name="type" column_id="3" system_type_id="175" 
  <c object_id="27" name="sid" column_id="4" system_type_id="165" u
  <c object_id="27" name="password" column_id="5" system_type_id="1
  <c object_id="27" name="dfltsch" column_id="6" system_type_id="23
  <c object_id="27" name="status" column_id="7" system_type_id="56"
  <c object_id="27" name="created" column_id="8" system_type_id="61
  <c object_id="27" name="modified" column_id="9" system_type_id="6
  <c object_id="27" name="deflanguage" column_id="10" system_type_i
</o>
```

The idea in short:

- Using `FOR XML AUTO` will created XML elements with the tables aliases as tags, while the attributes are the values.
- The XQuery expressions will look through any attribute anywhere in the XML.
- The predicate will filter  for elements answering the predicate.
- Using `sql:variable()` allows to introduce a variable's value into the XQuery.

This is - of course! - limited.

- The performance will be low.
- Using `*` will include any column, even huge BLOBs.
- Your approach creating a SQL-statement dynamically is probably better, but this depends on your needs...

Comment: too complicated, and I am searching big data, so performance is important

Comment: @MedAmin, Well, in this case you can dynamically add a column alias with something like `CONCAT(' AS ',QUOTENAME(CONCAT(tablename,'.',columnname)))`.

Comment: plz can you help me with an example, because I din't found the right query